# Undefined Control Sequence When Inserting Image

Tags: graphics

I know this has been asked many times but my environment is quite a bit different.

I'm writing a paper using [this project](https://github.com/stsewd/ieee-pandoc-template) in order to be able to use Markdown while still interacting with LaTeX.

When I use THE below code to insert a figure:

```
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=668px]{images/overall-architecture.png}
  \caption{The overall architecture.}
  \label{fig:overall-architecture}
\end{figure*}
```

I get the following error:

```
pandoc -o build/paper.pdf --bibliography=bibliography.bib --csl=bibliography.csl -s -f markdown --template=template.latex paper.md metadata.yaml                                                                
Error producing PDF.                                                                                                                                                                                            
! Undefined control sequence.                                                                                                                                                                                   
l.239     \includegraphics                                                                                                                                                                                      

make: *** [pdf] Error 43
```

I checked the `template.LaTeX` file inside the project I'm using and it has `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

Also, for some weird reason, the error regarding LaTeX gets resolved once I add an image via the Markdown syntax:

```
![](PATH_TO_IMAGE)
```

What's causing this error? As far as I can see, this is all valid LaTeX.

### UPDATE 1

[The LaTeX file](https://pastebin.com/eUcA5hGQ) created by `pandoc` during the process.

### UPDATE 2

As mentioned out by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer), there is an if clause in my `template.latex` file: `$if(graphics)$`

I commented out the if clause to see what happens, and the error changed to the following:

```
pandoc -o build/paper.pdf --bibliography=bibliography.bib --csl=bibliography.csl -s -f markdown --template=template.latex paper.md metadata.yaml
Error producing PDF.
! Too many }'s.
<recently read> }

l.39 }

make: *** [pdf] Error 43
```

Comment: We'll probably need to see the latex file generated by pandoc in order to help.

Comment: Sure, but at the moment, `pandoc` is not creating a separate output for LaTeX. Do you know the argument to make `pandoc` to do so? @daleif

Comment: No, I rarely use pandoc (eventhough it is a great tool), but there should be some option somewhere that asks it to keep the `.tex` file. You'd probably need to google it.

Comment: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#keeping_intermediate_tex

Comment: @daleif Please see the edit. Actually, it was really easy. Silly me, just changed the output format from `.pdf` to `.tex`. :] Also, after some research, I think the intermediate LaTeX output can't be retrieved when going from `.md` to `.pdf` but you should go from `.md` to .`tex`(for anyone interested).

Comment: If I run your latex file I get errors about missing image files but no error about `\includegraphics` not being defined

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I realized that as well but the LaTeX file is the one generated by `pandoc` so it should be the one being intermediately generated when it's creating the PDF. I don't know what else to say.

Comment: You need to find the log-file.

Comment: Oh. Just saw your remark about markdown image code. Did you create the latex file with or without it? Your template has an `$if(graphics)$` clause, if won't include the graphicx package if it doesn't know that there is an image in the file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The LaTeX file mentioned in my update remark is created including the markdown image code. However, just tried without it, and the errors are the same in the LaTeX side. Also, please see my second update regarding the `if` command

Comment: Did you also delete the $endif$ a few lines later?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sure did.

Comment: I tried with the paper.md from the github project and added an \includegraphics. I got your error and removing the `$if(graphics)$` and the `$endif$` solved the problem. Check if your system is uptodate. Compile your latex document directly with pdflatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Creating a `.tex` file with `pandoc` and then compiling it with `pdflatex` gives a similar error compared to the one I'm getting when I comment out the if statement and getting the `.pdf` output with `pandoc`. Also I checked my `pdflatex` version which is `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)`. Homebrew does not indicate an update. Is there a higher version source?